# Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\QuantityValidatorObserver Slow Performance

Tags: magento2

In my Magento 2.3.3 instance If I disable EVENT:sales_quote_item_qty_set_after , Observer: inventory then "/checkout/cart/" and "/checkout/" speeds up but it also remove ability to validated minimum quantity per product in a cart.

I have observered as the number of products increase in cart , "inventory" observe is taking longer and slowing overall mangento site.

It there any option to still maintain "minimum qty per product in a cart" while improve site performance. 
Or Is there option to improve perfromance of QuantityValidator Observer

> Validator :
>   Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\QuantityValidatorObserver EVENT :
>   sales_quote_item_qty_set_after  OBSERVER : inventory

Comment: How much time, are time taking `EVENT:sales_quote_item_qty_set_after` and on   how much products at cart?

Comment: It have ~1 sec per product. so if I have 4 product it eats up 4 secs.